# Menor Valor de um Conjunto de Colunas

Tags: r

Tenho um conjunto de dados e gostaria de selecionar apenas o menor valor entre cada chave primária. Segue o exemplo do meu DF:

```
ORDEM <- c(1,5,2,3,1,10)
GUIA <- c('111','111','333','333','555','555')
COR <- c('AZUL','AMARELO','PRETO','LARANJA','ROSA','VERDE')
DADOS <- data.frame(ORDEM,GUIA,COR)
```

Neste exemplo, são dois registros para cada chave (`GUIA`). Portanto, gostaria que o resultado aparecesse apenas o menor valor a partir da coluna `ORDEM`. O resultado que espero deve ser:

```
ORDEM <- c(1,2,1)
GUIA <- c('111','333','555')
COR <- c('AZUL','PRETO','ROSA')
DADOS_FINAL <- data.frame(ORDEM,GUIA,COR)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Com `dplyr` você pode fazer assim:

```
library(dplyr)
DADOS %>%  group_by(GUIA) %>% filter(ORDEM == min(ORDEM)) %>% ungroup()
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  ORDEM GUIA  COR  
  <dbl> <fct> <fct>
1     1 111   AZUL 
2     2 333   PRETO
3     1 555   ROSA
```